# React Table: row.original properties evaluating differently in the same console.log

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-table

I'am trying to get a `boolean` value out of my row data that exists on a particular row in my `React` Table. When I `console.log()` the row, and then the specific value within that row, the row shows the value as one thing when you expand the entire object, but the value itself evaluates differently within the same `console.log()`

```
Cell: row => {
    console.log('row: ', row.original, row.original.Saved);
    return <Field
           id={row.original.DataValueID}
           name='dataValueSelect'
           labelText: ''
           checked={row.original.Saved}
     />
}
```

*** CONSOLE ***

row:

```
{
  "id": 14624,
  "content": "AAAAA",
  "DataValueID": 14624,
  "DataKeyID": 78,
  "CreatedDate": "2019-06-21T19:53:56.393",
  "LastUpdated": "2019-06-21T19:53:56.393",
  "Saved": true
}
```

false

---

what prints out to the console is the row object as a whole with the Saved key set to value true, and then immediately afterwards when I log row.original.Saved value, it evaluates to false. I am not sure exactly why this is happening, but I need it to evaluate to what is in the row.original object, which it won't do when that value is passed as a property to that field.

Comment: Are you getting raw json like that when you log your row?  What happens if you print something like 'content' separately?

Comment: Yes, I am getting raw json back, and when I print content, the appropriate value gets printed.

Comment: What prints out if you do `console.log('row: ', JSON.parse(row.original), JSON.parse(row.original).Saved);`